# How to make Icon appear on Action Bar?

Tags: android, xml, icons

https://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/actionbar-actions.png

Where in my code do I type android:icon="@drawable/icon" to make the Icon appear to the left of the mTitle? I've tried looking in my layout and menu XMLs and I can't figure out where I'd type it to make my icon appear? I'm using a Navigation Drawer as my base template if that helps.

Comment: From what I understand You need to add an image view in your custom action bar to the right of Nav Drawer icon.

Comment: I'm using the Navigation Drawer Template in Eclipse - where would this file be? Menu XMLs? Layout XMLs?

Comment: I tried using this in the public void restoreActionBar() and nothing happened: actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

Comment: layout xml..add custom layout for action bar and include in all the   main xmls. hide the default action bar in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Manifest->Application, In Application there's Icon->Browse then change the icon of what you want or delete it..

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but my Icon isn't showing up on the Action Bar. Only on the Launcher.

Comment: did you put your icon in drawable? Then try to build.

Comment: I created my Icon as a Launcher Icon and placed it in the Icon Attribute in the Manifest (http://puu.sh/cop1n/b6cd7a8061.png). Do I have to create it as an Action Bar and Tab Icon or something? What would I do once I created that? There's only 1 slot for Icon in the Manifest?

Comment: What i mean is,1st you should put an image in your drawable folder. after that, open your manifest, then look for the application tag, under application tag, you will see android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher" <- change this to android:icon = "@drawable/nameofyourimagehere"

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I was able to change my Launcher icon. What I am trying to do is put my Icon to the left of my Title and the Right of my Nav Drawer like in this pic (do you see the white square? I think that is supposed to be the icon): http://puu.sh/copYc/be134708ef.png